# Will $lookup always load everything into memory?

Tags: mongodb

Will a $lookup always put the entire "looked up" documents fields into memory, even if there's a $project later that will select only a few fields?

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
    from: 'collection2',
    localField: 'reference_id',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'collection2'
  }},
  {$project: {
    ...
  }}
])
```

My question is, after the $lookup is executed, internally, there will be an array with everything from collection1 and collection2 loaded into memory? And only then the projection will happen?